# How to exit a while statement inside of a while statement to get back to the first while statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I put a `while` statement nested inside of another `while` statement and I'm wondering how I could exit/break the `while` to get to the other `while`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because reading a python book for 5 minutes or googling would be enough

Comment: Use a `break` statement.

Comment: I have found the command via greal. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `break` statement inside the inner loop to break it and resume iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Alright, i tried that and i got an error. is this being used right? `elif cmd == "logout":
                                break`

Comment: Please post your code here. Without that I can't really tell what kind of error appears and how to repair the code.

Comment: This is the error, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 58
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Comment: Are you sure? its a long code.

Comment: `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop` means you didn't put `break` inside the loop like I adviced :)

Comment: can i put `break` in a if or elif statement?

Comment: No, you can only put `break` to break loops.

Comment: alright, i have a `def` nested inside of a `def`. how do i get back to the old `def`

Comment: Use `return` to return from function

Comment: Alright. ill try that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example you can run:

```
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        if y == 5:
            break
        else:
            print "%s, %s" % (x, y)
```

Notice that even though `y` in the inner loop should reach a value of 9, it never gets higher than 4 because the inner loop is broken when `y == 5.`

Here is the output that I get when I run this:

```
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
0, 4
1, 0
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 0
2, 1
2, 2
2, 3
2, 4
3, 0
3, 1
3, 2
3, 3
3, 4
4, 0
4, 1
4, 2
4, 3
4, 4
5, 0
5, 1
5, 2
5, 3
5, 4
6, 0
6, 1
6, 2
6, 3
6, 4
7, 0
7, 1
7, 2
7, 3
7, 4
8, 0
8, 1
8, 2
8, 3
8, 4
9, 0
9, 1
9, 2
9, 3
9, 4
```